Applying Ito's Lemma to ${B_t}^2$
I am learning Stochastic Calculus and I encountered a practice question on applying Ito's lemma to $B_t^2$ where $B_t$ is the standard Brownian motion.
$$df(t,X_t) =\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + \mu_t \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\sigma_t^2}{2}\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}\right)dt+ \sigma_t \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\,dB_t$$
I tried two ways:

Let $X_t = B_t$, $dX_t = dB_t$ and $f(t, X_t) = X_t^2$ then I applied Ito's lemma to $f(t, X_t)$ where $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = 0$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 2X_t$ and $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2} = 2$. The drift term $\mu = 0$ and $\sigma_t = 1$.
Let $X_t = B_t^2$, $dX_t = 2B_tdB_t$ and $f(t, X_t) = X_t$ then I applied Ito's lemma to $f(t, X_t)$ where $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = 0$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 1$ and $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2} = 0$. The drift term $\mu = 0$ and $\sigma_t = 2B_t$.

(Update) Only the first yields the correct result
$$df(t,X_t) = dt + 2B_t dB_t$$
I am not sure about the second one as I used $dX_t = 2B_tdB_t$ which I suspect could be wrong if it is stochastic integral (written in the usual differential convention)? so the usual differentiation does not apply here.
Another related question stemmed from this is that in stochastic calculus, when can I apply the "usual" calculus operation?
I am a bit afraid to apply the "usual" calculus operation as I am afraid I would apply it wrongly to a situation where stochastic calculus should be applied.

@KurtG. so is the second way a completely no-go? Or what can I do to make it correct?

The way you are approacing it is a no-go. If you want $f(t,X_t)$ and $f(t,x)=x$ you need to know what $dX_t$ and $d\langle X\rangle_t$ is. Your $dX_t=2B_t,dB_t$ is it not.

@KurtG. Thank you!!! So the function/operation $f(t, X_t)$ should strictly be a "usual" function with differentiation and integration defined in the "usual" sense (I guessed)?

That was not my point. The more general Ito formula for a continuous semi martingale $X$ is $$df(t,X_t)=\partial_t f(t,X_t),dt+\partial_x f(t,X_t),dX_t+\frac12 \partial_{xx}f(t,X_t),d\langle X\rangle_t,.$$ Exercise for you: what is $dX_t$ and $d\langle X\rangle_t$ when $X_t=B_t^2,?$ Hint: use first bullet point. You should get the same result as with the other $f$ that was $f(t,B_t)=B_t^2,.$

@KurtG. I see what you meant. The Ito's lemma uses the stochastic integral (in differential form) of $X_t$ and $d \langle X \rangle _t$ (which relates to quadratic variation of $X_t$). and $f$ is just a usual operation/function on $X_t$ and this lemma tells us how to differentiate $f(t,X_t)$
